# Date Interval for Expiry Purpose

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to list all medicines which are going be expiry within 90 days, but I am getting syntax error, could anyone let me know about.

```
 Try
        If (Me.conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
            Me.conn.Open()
        End If
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(("
            select 
                ItemNo,Name,ManufacturerName,MedicineName,BatchNo,MedicineLocation,
                CostPrice,SellPrice,QtyAvailable,ExpiryDate,StockValue 
            from ItemTypes,Items 
            where ItemTypes.ItemTypesId=Items.ItemTypesId
              and ExpiryDate> '" & Strings.Format(DateAndTime.Now) & "' + INTERVAL 90 DAY "), conn)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dataSet, "dt")
        Me.dgrdItems.DataSource = dataSet.Tables.Item(0)
    Catch exception1 As Exception
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
        Dim exception As Exception = exception1
        Interaction.MsgBox(exception.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Nothing)
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
    End Try
```

Comment: What syntax error are you getting, and on what line?

Comment: if `ExpiryDate` is a date column, then dont pass a string: `and ExpiryDate> '" & Strings.Format(DateAndTime.Now) & "' + INTERVAL`

Comment: yes ExpiyDate is a coumn

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using a data base that doesn't understand `interval`.  Here is how you would express this query in SQL Server:

```
select ItemNo, Name, ManufacturerName, MedicineName, BatchNo, MedicineLocation,
        CostPrice, SellPrice, QtyAvailable, ExpiryDate, StockValue 
from ItemTypes join
     Items 
     on ItemTypes.ItemTypesId = Items.ItemTypesId
where ExpiryDate > getdate() + 90;
```

This makes two changes.  First it uses explicit `join` syntax rather than the archaic syntax of implicit joins in the `where` clause.  Second, it does the date comparison in the database.

Here is the `where` logic for some other databases:

MySQL:

```
where ExpiryDate > now() + interval 90 day
```

Oracle:

```
where ExpiryDate > sysdate + 90
```

Postgres:

```
where ExpiryDate > now() + interval '90 days'
```

Note that these also have time components, but those are usually easy to get rid of (in a database specific way).

Comment: now it is Ok, I just use the last portion of your code, but the problems that I don't want to show the expired medicines, I want to list medicines that from today within 90 days they will be expiry

Comment: @user3787279 . . . I don't understand.  Your question is rather explicit about the logic, because you have it in your `where` clause.  The question is simply about the syntax error, which this answers.  If you have a logic question, I would suggest that you ask another question, include sample data and desired results.  And, tag the question with the appropriate database.

Comment: Simply change the condition from "greater than" to "less than [or equal] and maybe add another condition "greater than today"